# Excel VBA Which UserForm Control Triggered Shared MouseOver Class Event?

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, user-controls, mouseover

How do I return the name of the userform control that triggered the mouseover class event?

This sounds so simple but honestly I've been racking my brain trying to find the correct syntax...

Here is my userform module:

```
Option Explicit
Dim dArray() As New Class1

Sub Build_Controls()
Dim dImage As Object, i As Integer

For i = 1 To 3
Set dImage = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.Image.1", i, True)
    With dImage
        .Left = (25 * i) + 20
        .Width = 20
        .Top = 10
        .Height = 20
    End With
    ReDim Preserve dArray(1 To i)
    Set dArray(i).dImages = dImage
Next i

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Build_Controls
End Sub
```

I dynamically create three image controls at runtime aptly named "1", "2", and "3".

I assign each control a mouseover event found in the following class module called "Class1":

```
Public WithEvents dImages As MSForms.Image
Private Sub dImages_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
MsgBox ("Control Name") 'Which control was triggered?
End Sub
```

How can I make the MsgBox contain the name of the control that triggered the event?

```
Me.dImages.Name              'x
ActiveControl.Name           'x
Screen.ActiveControl.Name    'x    
UserForm1.ActiveControl.Name 'x
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Mr. J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this in the class module

do not use `msgbox` because it puts the VBA editor into background

use `Debug.Print`, then you can watch the values change on the fly in the `immediate window`

put a breakpoint at the debug.print line and then examine the `dImages` object in the `watch window` ( that is how i got the `name` attribute )

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents dImages As MSForms.Image
'

Private Sub dImages_Click()
    Debug.Print dImages.Name
End Sub
'

Private Sub dImages_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Debug.Print dImages.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: I knew it would be simple! I was certain I'd tried this... Thanks for your tip about the immediate window, I need to use this more often.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: seems like I mis-read your question, but

```
Msgbox dImages.Name
```

works for me  /EDIT

```
Msgbox dImages.Parent.Name
```

or something like that - you have a reference to the control in dImages, so you just need to go "up" from there.

If the control isn't hosted directly on the form then you will need to go "up" using `.Parent` until the parent is not another control:

```
Dim tmp As Object
Set tmp = dImages.Parent
Do While TypeOf tmp Is MSForms.Control
    Set tmp = tmp.Parent
Loop
MsgBox tmp.Name
```

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/758496-get-userform-given-control.html

Comment: This only seems to return the name of the userform the control belongs to, not the actual control itself. I can reference all the properties of the control using `dImages` apart from the control name. As you said, using `.Parent` goes a stage higher in the hierarchy to the userform.