# Creating MouseOver Effects using Object Classes

Tags: excel, vba, class, events, mouseover

I am attempting to assign mouse hover effects on my images on the form based on the TAG attribute that I assign to them. I want only certain photos to have effects applied when the mouse hits them. My difficulty is getting the code to work. I have no issue with it when you are making a new object, but this code requires a loop through controls to find the ones I want the feature applied. I have attached the code to hopefully explain the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

**CLASS MODULE** cls_ProjectManager_Controls

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents zImage As MSForms.Image
Private index_image As Long

Sub SetImage(ctl As MSForms.Image, ByRef Index As Long)
    Set zImage = ctl
    index_image = Index
End Sub

Private Sub zImage_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    zImage.BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
   
End Sub
```

**Normal Module**

```
Option Explicit

Private pmImageCollection As Collection


Sub initializePropertyManagerControls()

Dim xImage As cls_ProjectManager_controls
Dim x_image As MSForms.Image
Dim ctl As Control
Dim index_image As Long
Dim i As Long

'check that collection is not already empty, if not empty; set the index counter
If pmImageCollection Is Nothing Then
    Set pmImageCollection = New Collection
    index_image = 1
Else
    index_image = pmImageCollection.Count + 1
End If


For Each ctl In frmMasterForm.form_multipage.Pages(2).Controls
    If ctl.Tag = "eff_Small_Button" Then
        Set x_image = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.Image.1")
       
        With x_image
            
            Set xImage = New cls_ProjectManager_controls
            xImage.SetImage x_image, index_image
            pmImageCollection.Add xImage
        
        End With
        
        index_image = index_image + 1
    End If
Next ctl

End Sub
```

As you can see it adds the items to collection, but the last effect(addition of border) does not trigger. I have tried rewriting the code from my readings on other similar posts, like this one
[Excel VBA Which UserForm Control Triggered Shared MouseOver Class Event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899841/excel-vba-which-userform-control-triggered-shared-mouseover-class-event) but this code creates controls during the runtime. I am new to the use of Classes so I am unsure how this affects my code.

Comment: Looks like it it will trigger, but an added image probably has already a border, so you can't see a change. Add a debug.print in your zImage_MouseMove

Comment: I have added the debugg.print  zImage.Name to the _MouseMove code, but I did not see any printout to the Immediate window during runtime. I have also tried another effect like visability = false but that too does not trigger.